# Add existing fields to new screen

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to add Purchase order screen's OrderNbr and OrderType fields to a newly created screen.

I am getting view doesn't exist error on the screen for OrderType selector. Attached the graph and DAC associated with the screen

```
    public PXSave<PONextAction> Save;
    public PXCancel<PONextAction> Cancel;        
    public PXFilter<PONextAction> MasterView;

    [PXProjection(typeof(Select<POOrder>), Persistent = true)]
    [Serializable]
    public partial class PONextAction : IBqlTable
    {
        #region OrderType
        public abstract class orderType : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected String _OrderType;
        [PXDBString(2, IsKey = true, IsFixed = true, BqlField = typeof(POOrder.orderType))]
        [PXDefault()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "PO Type", Enabled = true)]
        [PX.Objects.PO.POOrderType.List()]
        public virtual String OrderType
        {
            get
            {
                return this._OrderType;
            }
            set
            {
                this._OrderType = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region OrderNbr
        public abstract class orderNbr : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        protected String _OrderNbr;
        [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true, InputMask = "", BqlField = typeof(POOrder.orderNbr))]
        [PXDefault()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "PO Nbr.", Enabled = true)]
        [PXSelector(typeof(Search<POOrder.orderNbr, Where<POOrder.orderType, Equal<Current<POLinePM.orderType>>>>), DescriptionField = typeof(POOrder.orderDesc))]
        public virtual String OrderNbr
        {
            get
            {
                return this._OrderNbr;
            }
            set
            {
                this._OrderNbr = value;
            }
        }
        #endregion

    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you copied the `POOrderR Alias DAC` pattern. Alias DAC are typically used when you need to have two current object of the same DAC in memory at the same time.

Your use case doesn't require that. Do not create a new DAC, reuse the `POOrder` DAC (not POOrder**R**). I'm not sure why you created a new DAC, maybe it's to avoid custom fields showing elsewhere? If that's the case you can look into the Visible/Visibility properties instead.